# Not clear how to correctly define lifetime for struct

Tags: rust

I have TCP Client, which process some handlers. I need to share data between them, so I implemented `Session` struct for this case:

```
struct Session<'a> {
    pub session_key: Option<&'a Vec<u8>>,
    pub username: Option<&'a str>,
    pub password: Option<&'a str>,
}

impl Session {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            session_key: None,
            username: None,
            password: None,
       }
    }
}
```

I added access by reference to allow data be borrowed.
But, when I try to use this struct inside my code, I got errors related to lifetime:

> implicit elided lifetime not allowed here

or

> cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements

This is [minimal sandbox implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=000daf00664a5b832f8ac5273d1aa068).

Just in case this is my sample code (mostly it's similar to my real app):

```
// data which store values that I need to share between handlers
struct Session<'a> {
    pub session_key: Option<&'a Vec<u8>>,
    pub username: Option<&'a str>,
    pub password: Option<&'a str>,
}

// not sure if this correct to set &None below, where to put the lifetime here ?
impl Session {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            session_key: None,
            username: None,
            password: None,
        }
    }
}

// what handler return
pub enum HandlerResponse {
    Packet(Vec<u8>),
    Void,
}

// handler params
pub struct HandlerInput<'a> {
    session: &'a mut Session<'a>,
    data: Option<Vec<u8>>
}

pub struct Client<'a> {
    stream: Option<TcpStream>,
    buffer: [u8; 4096],
    session: Session<'a>,
}

// public methods
impl<'a> Client<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            stream: None,
            buffer: [0u8; 4096],
            session: Session::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn connect(&mut self, host: &str, port: i16) {
        let addr = format!("{}:{}", host, port);
        match TcpStream::connect(&addr) {
            Ok(stream) => {
                self.stream = Some(stream);
                println!("Connected to {}", addr);
            },
            _ => {
                println!("Cannot connect");
            },
        }
    }

    pub fn handle_connection(
        &mut self, 
        handlers: Vec<fn(HandlerInput
    ) -> Result<u8, Error>>) {
        for handler in handlers {
            self.process(handler);
        }
    }
}

// private methods
impl<'a> Client<'a> {
    fn process<F>(&mut self, handler: F)
    where
        F: Fn(HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerResponse, Error>
    {
        let response: Result<HandlerResponse, Error> = match self.handle_read() {
            Ok(server_response) => handler(HandlerInput {
                session: &mut self.session,
                data: Some(server_response),
            }),
            _ => handler(HandlerInput {
                session: &mut self.session,
                data: None,
            })
        };

        match response.unwrap() {
            HandlerResponse::Packet(data) => {
                self.handle_write(data).unwrap();
            },
            HandlerResponse::Void => {},
        }
    }

    fn handle_write(&mut self, packet: Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let mut stream = self.stream.as_ref().unwrap();

        match stream.write(&packet) {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
            _ => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Write error")),
        }
    }

    fn handle_read(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error> {
        let mut stream = self.stream.as_ref().unwrap();
        let mut buffer = self.buffer.as_mut();

        match stream.read(&mut buffer) {
            Ok(bytes_count) => {
                return Ok(buffer[ .. bytes_count].to_vec());
            },
            _ => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Read error")),
        }
    }
}
```

When I put lifetime on `Client` struct and then put lifetime on `&'a mut self` I got an error:

> cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements

Could you explain how to fix lifetimes here ?

**UPDATED:**
I need a reference inside `Session` because I want to use the values of the session inside handlers, if I not use reference, I got the error:

> move occurs because `input.session.session_key` has type `Option<Vec<u8>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

The code how I use the `Session`:

```
fn handler(input: HandlerInput) {
    let hasher = Sha1::new();
    let digest = hasher
        .chain(input.session.username.unwrap())
        .chain(input.session.session_key.unwrap())
        .finalize();
}
```

Also sometimes I need to modify the input inside handler, something like:

```
let mut session = input.session;
session.session_key = Some(srp_client.session_key());
```

Comment: Note that `&Vec<T>` is almost always wrong. Use `&[T]`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman could you explain why ?

Comment: It is less general and less performant.

Comment: See: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/2189130)

Comment: The `&Vec<T>` vs `&[T]` discussion is interesting and true and all, but totally off-topic imo.
The real question I have is: Why store references in a struct in the first place? Are you really sure you want that? And not some reference-counting thing instead like `Rc`/`Arc`?

Comment: Or just plain values, now that I think about it? I don't see why the `Session` can't just take ownership of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two problems:

- Your short sample code is missing lifetime annotations
- Your longer code is an implementation that is almost impossible to achieve with borrows, and therefore I suspect that this question is an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

---

### Quick fix of your short code sample

Your `impl` is missing lifetimes:

```rust
pub struct Session<'a> {
    pub session_key: Option<&'a Vec<u8>>,
    pub username: Option<&'a str>,
    pub password: Option<&'a str>,
}

impl<'a> Session<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            session_key: None,
            username: None,
            password: None,
       }
    }
}
```

---

### What you probably actually want

So my question is, why use borrows in the first place for `Session`?
You technically only need the reference in `HandlerInput`. Then, both handlers see the same `Session` object to modify.

```
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind, Read, Write};
use std::net::TcpStream;

// data which store values that I need to share between handlers
struct Session {
    pub session_key: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    pub username: Option<String>,
    pub password: Option<String>,
}

// not sure if this correct to set &None below, where to put the lifetime here ?
impl Session {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            session_key: None,
            username: None,
            password: None,
        }
    }
}

// what handler return
pub enum HandlerResponse {
    Packet(Vec<u8>),
    Void,
}

// handler params
pub struct HandlerInput<'a> {
    session: &'a mut Session,
    data: Option<Vec<u8>>,
}

pub struct Client {
    stream: Option<TcpStream>,
    buffer: [u8; 4096],
    session: Session,
}

// public methods
impl Client {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            stream: None,
            buffer: [0u8; 4096],
            session: Session::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn connect(&mut self, host: &str, port: i16) {
        let addr = format!("{}:{}", host, port);
        match TcpStream::connect(&addr) {
            Ok(stream) => {
                self.stream = Some(stream);
                println!("Connected to {}", addr);
            }
            _ => {
                println!("Cannot connect");
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn handle_connection(
        &mut self,
        handlers: Vec<fn(HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerResponse, Error>>,
    ) {
        for handler in handlers {
            self.process(handler);
        }
    }
}

// private methods
impl Client {
    fn process<F>(&mut self, handler: F)
    where
        F: Fn(HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerResponse, Error>,
    {
        let response: Result<HandlerResponse, Error> = match self.handle_read() {
            Ok(server_response) => handler(HandlerInput {
                session: &mut self.session,
                data: Some(server_response),
            }),
            _ => handler(HandlerInput {
                session: &mut self.session,
                data: None,
            }),
        };

        match response.unwrap() {
            HandlerResponse::Packet(data) => {
                self.handle_write(data).unwrap();
            }
            HandlerResponse::Void => {}
        }
    }

    fn handle_write(&mut self, packet: Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let mut stream = self.stream.as_ref().unwrap();

        match stream.write(&packet) {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
            _ => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Write error")),
        }
    }

    fn handle_read(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error> {
        let mut stream = self.stream.as_ref().unwrap();
        let mut buffer = self.buffer.as_mut();

        match stream.read(&mut buffer) {
            Ok(bytes_count) => {
                return Ok(buffer[..bytes_count].to_vec());
            }
            _ => Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, "Read error")),
        }
    }
}

fn handler1(input: HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerResponse, Error> {
    Ok(HandlerResponse::Void)
}

fn handler2(input: HandlerInput) -> Result<HandlerResponse, Error> {
    Ok(HandlerResponse::Void)
}

fn main() {
    let mut client = Client::new();
    client.connect("127.0.0.1", 8080);
    client.handle_connection(vec![handler1, handler2]);
}
```

Compiles fine and should work.

Comment: I updated my question, could you please check ? I added the examples, why (from my point of view) I need the references inside `Session`. In short, when I tried to access the fields from `Session` directly, using `HandlerInput`, I got an error that move occurs.

Comment: I think this is a completely unrelated question. Please open another StackOverflow question with another minimal reproducible example. You will never be able to store references in `Session`, because `handler1` will never be able to match lifetimes of `handler2`. Further, every variable you create in a handler will get dropped at the end of the handler function, making it impossible to store a reference to it in an external object.

Comment: You say "I need to store a reference because otherwise you get an error" - I think storing a reference is not the proper way to get rid of that error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation, I finally fixed the issue: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d442c12b80a398db033a73574776d4f5, just added .as_ref(), so no need to store references or define lifetimes.

Comment: That sounds more reasonable :)